# Python: retrieve values after index in each column of table

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get a table with values after each cell = 100 in a table. Is there an efficient method for completing this?

Now:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    89   100  92
2    100  14   88
3    75   18   100
4    34   56   63
```

To:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    nan  100  nan
2    100  14   nan
3    75   18   100
4    34   56   63
```

I've tried:

```
for row in data:
    empty.append(str(np.where(element == 100 for element in row)));
for i in empty:
    #Not sure what to do next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized approach for your problem:

```
>>> a = np.array([[89, 100, 92], [100, 14, 88],
...               [75, 18, 100], [34, 56, 63]])
>>> first100 = np.argmax(a == 100, axis=0)
>>> first100
array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
>>> mask = rows[:, None] < first100
>>> mask
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> out = a.astype(float)
>>> out[mask] = np.nan
>>> out
array([[  nan,  100.,   nan],
       [ 100.,   14.,   nan],
       [  75.,   18.,  100.],
       [  34.,   56.,   63.]])
```

Comment: What is the variable rows?

Comment: Haven't seen you for a while, but Neat solution! It is bit of strange that `numpy` does not have a build-in `cummax` like `R`.

Comment: `rows=np.array([0,1,2,3])`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `pandas`, but if you don't you will probably need a cumulative maximum function:

```
In [37]:

a
Out[37]:
array([[ 89, 100,  92],
       [100,  14,  88],
       [ 75,  18, 100],
       [ 34,  56,  63]], dtype=int64)
In [38]:

def cummax(a):
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i==0:
            result.append(a[0])
        else:
            result.append(max(a[:i+1]))
    return np.array(result)
In [39]:

np.where(np.apply_along_axis(cummax, 0, a)>=100, a, np.nan)
Out[39]:
array([[  nan,  100.,   nan],
       [ 100.,   14.,   nan],
       [  75.,   18.,  100.],
       [  34.,   56.,   63.]])
```

Comment: Ignore the second question.I'm using numpy. Will I have to transpose my matrix after running the code as I want the columns to only be affected which seems to be the transpose of your final array.

Comment: No Sir, in that case, just change it to `np.apply_along_axis(cummax, 0, a)` (1->0). :)

Comment: If I have a dataset like stated in the opening post, is the function implemented via:

a = np.transpose(data);  np.where(np.apply_along_axis(cummax(a), 0, a)>=100, a, np.nan)

Comment: Edited, if you are using `pandas`, there is a build-in `cummax`, otherwise @Jaime 's solution would be the better choice.